# Set author and creation date in Excel comments using Office.js

Tags: excel, office-js

I need to set Excel comments and replies programmatically using Office.js.

I've got no issue with setting the content, but I'm not able to modify the author and the creation date, it always appears that the comment is set by the user connected and at the time the procedure runs.

Is there a way to change these properties?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on our design the comment author and create date are read-only properties, it cannot be changed. As when a comment was created, the author and create date became the facts of this comment.

The document can be found at 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.comment?view=excel-js-preview#authorname

Comment: Understood your point. I'll try to show mine: we have a service that gets data and comments from somewhere else and needs to show them in the workbook. Basically someone writes a comment in a Workbook and a second Workbook gather and show everybody's comments.

Comment: Do you think these properties could be set as writeable in future?

Comment: Thanks Luca, so far we dont have plan to make these properties writable. from your scenario, the 2nd workbook is also presented it via comments? i thought it should be listed the comment detail via a table.

Comment: Well, we don't think that way would work given client needs. Anyway, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This is also not allow via UI. because a user adds a comment via UI menu, he/she is not able to change the create date and author. therefore our API will not support this behavior.  I am sorry about that.